# How to make a query that return data of rows related to each row in table

Tags: sql

i have some tables about Double-entry bookkeeping.

table VoucherDetail Contains Accounting Entries for Each Voucher and
other tables are Accounts Group/Ledger/Definitive

here are diagrams of tables
[image: current results]

im trying to get opposite side of an entry and show it in a custom column that matches entry debit/credit amount(Ref to image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Vwr.jpg)).

i did some google search and find nothing. here is the query i made so far(Ref to image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lEor.jpg)):

```sql
SELECT
    dbo.Vouchers.VoucherId,
    vd.VoucherDetailIndex AS ind,
    vd.Debit,
    vd.Credit,
    vd.Description,
    CONCAT ( ag.Name, '_', al.Name, '_', ad.Name ) AS names,
    CONCAT ( ag.GroupId, '_', al.LedgerId, '_', ad.DefinitiveId ) AS ids 

FROM dbo.Vouchers

    JOIN dbo.VoucherDetails AS vd ON vd.Voucher_VoucherIndex = dbo.Vouchers.VoucherIndex
    JOIN dbo.AccDefinitives AS ad ON vd.AccDefinitive_DefinitiveIndex = ad.DefinitiveIndex
    JOIN dbo.AccLedgers AS al ON ad.AccLedger_LedgerIndex = al.LedgerIndex
    JOIN dbo.AccGroups AS ag ON al.AccGroup_GroupIndex = ag.GroupIndex
```

here is the result im getting :

[image: current results]

result i want to be :

[image: desired results]

here is an example to explain what i need :
EVENT : 
we put 10$ on bank as our Equity, now we need to create a voucher for this:

```sql
INSERT INTO Vouchers(VoucherIndex, VoucherId, VoucherDate, Description) VALUES
(1, 1, 2019/01/01, initial investment);
```

and now we need to add Entry of this event to VoucherDetail of Voucher 1
which will have 2 entry; 1 for cash and 1 for Equity :

```sql
INSERT INTO VoucherDetails(VoucherDetailIndex, Debit, Credit, Description AccDefinitive_DefinitiveIndex, AccLedger_LedgerIndex, Voucher_VoucherIndex, EntityOrder) VALUES
(1, 10$, 0, 'Put Cash on Bank as initial Investment', 10101, 101, 1, 1),
(2, 0, 10$, 'initial Investment', 50101, 501, 1, 2);
```

now we run the first query i provided here is the result

[image: current results]

now we have our common result, lets get to the problem

imagine someone filled these tables with 10000 row data

and we need to find Voucher no.10, with 20 entries inside VoucherDetail
we get these entries by doing a simple query.

but we don't know which related to which(like in above example Cash with 10$ debt related to Equity with 10$ credit)

if we want to know it, we need to spend time on it every time we need to find something

the query need to search whole table and find opposite side related to each row based on Debit or Credit value of row

this should be the result i wrote in excel :
[image: current results]

as you can see in the image above there is 2 new columns added
Account in opposite Side and Account ID in opposite side

first row refers to Equity which related to Cash  and
second row refers to Cash Which related to Equity.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify your problem. [mcve]

Comment: sorry my english knowledge is low so i tried to describe as much as i can.

Comment: It looks to me like you need to join again against the dbo.Acc* tables, but using the foreign key from Voucher or VoucherDetails that represents the opposite side of the voucher. It's not clear though from your question what that field might be called.

Comment: updated first post as much as i can, @jarlh can you help? thanks

Comment: can you check it again @RobStreeting, Thanks

Comment: Thanks for updating the post, I can see now that you have multiple VoucherDetail records for the same VoucherID (a.k.a. Voucher_VoucherIndex) that you need to link together on a single row. The difficulty here is that there's nothing in common between the records to link other than VoucherID and the relationship between the Debit and Credit numbers. One final clarification before I write an answer - can you have the same Debit value in multiple VoucherDetail records that have the same VoucherID?

Comment: they can be same values too @RobStreeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, what you need to be able to do is join two VoucherDetail records that have the same Voucher_VoucherIndex value (let's call this VoucherID for brevity). However, the only two things these records have in common is their VoucherID and the fact that the Debit value = the Credit value in the other, and vice versa.

In the comments you mentioned that multiple VoucherDetail rows with the same VoucherID can have the same Debit value (and I presume Credit value). If this wasn't the case, you could add something like this to your query:

```
    JOIN dbo.VoucherDetails AS vd_opposite
        ON vd.Voucher_VoucherIndex = vd_opposite.Voucher_VoucherIndex
        AND (vd.Debit = vd_opposite.Credit OR vd.Credit = vd_opposite.Debit)
```

You can't do this though, because Debit/Credit and VoucherID together are not enough to be unique, so you might pick up extra rows in the join that you don't want.

Therefore, your only option is to add a new ID field to your table (maybe called SaleID or something) that definitively links the two rows that represent opposite sides of the same "sale" with a common ID. Then, the above JOIN would look like this:

```
    JOIN dbo.VoucherDetails AS vd_opposite
        ON vd.Voucher_VoucherIndex = vd_opposite.Voucher_VoucherIndex
        AND vd.SaleID = vd_opposite.SaleID
```

In addition to adding that JOIN, you would need to join the new `vd_opposite` table against all of the dbo.Acc* tables again to get access to the data you want, and obviously add the fields from those tables that you want in the results to your SELECT fields.

Comment: likely its working, but gives duplicate values i used DISTINCT to remove duplicate ones thank you for answer, i will be waiting for more people to see what they can do too